# Did this real analysis exam question went wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

while studieng for my real analysis exam I work through older exams, and stumbled over the following task

(I copied it 1 to 1):

---

Show that for any $q\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ the following identity holds:

$$\sum^n_{k=1}(1-q)^{k-1}q^{n-k}=1$$

---

I figured they want me to probably use induction on this and worked till the inductionstep with:

$\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}(1-q)^{k-1}q^{n-k}=\sum^n_{k=1}(1-q)^{k-1}q^{n-k}+(1-q)^nq^{-1}=1+(1-q)^nq^{-1}$ (using the induction hypothesis)

Here I kept stucking until I figured maybe the examquestion is wrong.. and for $n=4$ and $q=\frac{1}{3}$

wolfram alpha indeed tells me the identity stated above doesnt hold.

So is the exam question wrong? And if its wrong, what went wrong (what is missing?) I suspect a missing binomial coefficient..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a factor $n \choose k$ in the sum.  The proof is expanding $1^n=((1-q)+q)^n$ with the binomial theorem.